# using ng-repeat to display data in json file

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs. I want to display the data in the following json file using ng-repeat.

http://www.cricbuzz.com/api/match/current

But I'm confused as there is a number in the data as key to each object. Can someone help me?

Comment: Help with what? We don't know what you are confused about . What is the specific problem? Please show all relevant code in the question itself not in external links

Comment: search some example and come up with some effort .

Answer (score 0):

THis is a basic way to do it

***Partial***

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" >
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">                       
                    <td>#{{ row.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.series.name | uppercase }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

***Controller***

```
angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Resource', function ($scope, Resource) {

            var pageChanged = function () {
                $scope.myPromise = Resource.get({}, function (response) {
                  $scope.rows = response;
                });
            };

            pageChanged();

}])
.factory('Resource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://www.cricbuzz.com/api/match/current', {
        }, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
            }
        });
        }]);
```

Comment: But that code is not doing anything. It doesn't even sending a request to the url.

Comment: Show me your code and i'll help you, in a working app this should send a request

Comment: I edited the answer to include a posible issue... the new div tells angular  to attach the "Ctrl" controller class to the view

Comment: Please check this fiddle and tell me where I'm doing wrong. [http://jsfiddle.net/4u9g6my9/](http://jsfiddle.net/4u9g6my9/)